# Nginx: root path relative to conf file

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to specify `root` path relative to the containing conf file?

We are developing a web app and keep `app-nginx.conf` file with app-specific configuration in the project's directory. I want to be able to include this file into main `nginx.conf` and have `root` path properly referencing required project's sub-directory. Example:

```
# /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
http {
    include /absolute/path/to/app/app-nginx.conf
}


# /absolute/path/to/app/app-nginx.conf
server {
    server_name localhost;
    listen 9090;

    root ./app;
}
```

After starting nginx with similar configuration nginx tries to resolve `./app` path relative to nginx installation directory (`/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.3/` in my case), not to the app's directory.

Answer (score 13):

> Is it possible to specify root path relative to the containing conf file?

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Nginx, by default, only knows about the path such as `--prefix` and `--conf-path` that are set at the compile time (ref: https://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html). We can find various paths used by Nginx by running the command `nginx -V` (it's capital "V"). So, `--conf-path` is where the main `nginx.conf` file resides and *that* path is used for any relative paths.

According to the official documentation (https://nginx.org/r/root), a `root` directive can contain other variables, though.

Thanks for @cyker for clarifying after 5 years of posting the initial answer!

Comment: Thank you, Pothi. Unfortunately neither of the options works for me. `--prefix` can affect other nginx servers and from my personal perspective a little bit harder to manage comparing to configuration file. And nginx doesn't allow to create custom variables with `set` directive outside `server` context, so I can't move absolute path from my app-nginx.conf file.

Comment: *So, that path is used for any relative paths.* I think this is inaccurate. It seems nginx will use config dir for options `include` and `ssl_certificate`, for example, but will use prefix dir for options such as `root`. I don't seem to come up with a full list about which one each option uses.

Comment: @Cyker You are right. Updated the answer now. Of course, it isn't complete. But, better than the original answer (that was indeed wrong / inaccurate).

Comment: I'm reading Nginx From Beginner to Pro, it's noted that: "You have already seen the usage of root directive inside a location block. The root directive tells Nginx to
return /image/myimage.jpg instead of fully qualified path /etc/nginx/html/app1/image/myimage.jpg." so IMHO it means that Nginx config support relative pathes ?

Comment: Here, the question is specific to "root" directive and whether it could support "relative path to conf file".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to use relative paths or define global variables, but [this little trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433309/how-to-define-a-global-variable-in-nginx-conf-file/14447286#14447286) solves my problem.

Comment: What little trick?

Comment: I can't define variable, but I can use `map` directive with single `default` value that will play role of the variable for me.